# Using refresh token to get new authorization token and repeat failed api call

Tags: swift, rest, networking, callback, swiftui

I have a general question about using tokens in swift to make api calls. The authorization token that is needed to make api calls expires every hour so I need a way to handle this in a generalized way for multiple api calls.

I'm facing an issue where if I get a 401 error I call a function to use the refresh token to get a new authorization token and I would like to re call the original function that gotten 401 error.

For example:

If I get a 401 error when I call `getDetails()` I want to call the `getNewAuthToken()` and after I get a new refresh token I want to call  `getDetails()` again.

I want to do this in a way so that if I call any function `getX()` and I get a 401 error it calls `getNewAuthToken()` and then it calls the original function again  `getX()`

What would be the best way to approach this without using any external libraries etc. Would the best way be using a sort of callback function ?

I have provided general code I've been implementing but as you can see when I get a 401 error it calls the `getNewAuthToken()` function but the original function is not called again. How can this code be modified to behave as needed?

```
import UIKit
import Combine

@Published var details: Details = nil

func getNewAuthToken(){
// here I request a token using the refresh token

}

func getDetails(){
    self.getCurrentDetails{ details in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.details = details
        }
    }
}

func getCurrentDetails(_ completionHandler: @escaping (Details) -> ()) {
    let url = "https://api.xxx.com/details"
    guard let detailsURL = URL(string: url) else{
        fatalError("URL not valid")
    }
    let authtoken = keychain.get("authtoken") ?? ""
    var request = URLRequest(url: detailsURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("Bearer \(authtoken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request){
        data, response, error in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        // I request a new token
        if(httpResponse?.statusCode == 401){
            print("401")
            self.getNewAuthToken()
            return
        }
        do {
            if(httpResponse?.statusCode != 200){
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let details = try decoder.decode(Details.self, from:
                data!)
            completionHandler(details)

        } catch  let error2{
            print(error2)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to separate function like "getX()" to handle this. All you need is a completion handler.

```
func getNewAuthToken(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
// here I request a token using the refresh token
    completionHandler()
}

func someNetworkCall() {
    getNewAuthToken {
        someNetworkCall()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would only call getNewAuthToken if I get a 401 error. In the code I pasted the flow would be as follows: I would call getDetails(), which would then call getCurrentDetails() there I would get a 401 error which would then call the getNewAuthToken(). After I get a new auth token getDetails() or getCurrentDetails()  would get called again to fulfill that original request.

Comment: Yes that is the plan.

Comment: Can you electorate a bit more ?

Comment: You explained the flow. I said that correct. I don't think I have anything else to explain.